# Describing vectors: why do we need one angle in 2D, but three in 3D?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

When describing vectors in 2D, we need one angle. Why do we need three angles when describing vectors in 3D? I've tried thinking about this in depth, but I'm stumped. It seems like we'd need two and that's it.

Comment: Why do you think you need three angles? - Which source did you hear that from?

Comment: I think you mean, why you require 3 angles to describe a point in $R^3$ (space). To define a point, it's position vector would require 3 angles and hence the three coordinates $(x,y,z)$

Comment: I'm studying directional cosines and it shows that a vector has 3 angular components. One in relation to x, another in relation to y, and the last in relation to z.

Comment: @imclaytonwuut Using just two directional cosines would restrict the vector to a two dimensional space only, the z-component allows the vector's free movement in space at any configuration.

Comment: Imagine that you are standing upright staring straight forward. You can rotate left or right (first angle) and you can move your head up or down (second angle). Are you missing any point (in space)?

Comment: No? I don't think so, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You only need two to uniquely define the vector's direction, but if you want to define "roll" you need a third angle.

Answer (score 0):

To describe the *position* of a point in 3D you need only two angles, but to describe the *orientation* of a 3D object requires three degrees of freedom.

But in 2D we only need *one* degree of freedom to describe orientation (rotation in the plane), so what links the 2D and 3D case? It is precisely the following:

Say that two planes (through the origin) $A, B$ are *partially orthogonal* if there are vectors $0\ne a \in A$ and $0 \ne b \in B$ such that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal. In 2D, you can have at most one plane because there is only one; in 3D, you can have at most three pairwise partially-orthogonal (PPO) planes. This reasoning extends to 4D, where you can have six PPO planes, and so need six degrees of freedom to describe the orientation of a body. In general, in dimension $n$ there are at most
$$
  {n\choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}2
$$
PPO planes, and this is how many degrees of freedom you need to describe an orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Given any two non-zero vectors, the cosine of the angle between
them is defined as the
[direction cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine#General_meaning). In $n$-dimensional
space there are $n$ mutually orthogonal coordinate vectors from
the origin. Hence, given an arbitrary non-zero vector, there are
$n$ direction cosines, one between each of the coordinate vectors
and the given vector. It is easy to show that sum of the squares
of these cosines is equal to $1$. For example, in two dimensions,
$\,\cos(\theta_1)^2 + \cos(\theta_2)^2 = 1.\,$ The two angles are
complementary to each other. However, the cosine is an even function
so that given only $\,\cos(\theta_1)\,$ all we know is that
$\,\cos(\theta_2) = \pm\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta_1)^2}.\,$ There are two
possible values for $\,\cos(\theta_2)\,$ and for each of those two
values of $\,\theta_2.\,$ The same thing happens in $n$ dimensions.
Given any $\,n-1\,$ of the direction cosines, the remaining direction
Despite this, in $n$ dimensions, the values of all of the $n$
direction cosines of a given vector determines the direction of
the vector uniquely although there is a dependency between them.

A related construction is given by the use in $n$-dimensional space of
[spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

> in which the coordinates consist of a radial coordinate $r$, and $n-1$ angular coordinates
> and here only $n-1$ angles are needed to specify the direction of a
> non-zero vector.